# In Ansible while using expect and send in Shell module send is not working properly

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I tried Shell module's "expect" and "send" feature, code is running but its not sending the password, it's just exiting from the playbook.

```
 ---
    - hosts: localhost
      become: yes
      vars:
      - remote_password: redhat
      tasks:
      - name: connecting to a remote host not an ansible slave
        shell: |
         set timeout 300
         spawn ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.48.133
         expect "password: "
         send "{{ remote_password }}\n"
         interact
         exit 0
        args:
         executable: /usr/bin/expect
```

---

### Output:

```
 "stdout_lines": [
        "spawn ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.48.133",
        "/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: \"/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub\"",
        "/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed",
        "/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys",
        "root@192.168.48.133's password: "
    ]
}
```

Don't know why this isn't working. Why it's not providing the password.

Comment: Is that expect script working as expected when ran manually on the host ? Did you try without the space at the end of your expected output ? => `expect "password:"`

Comment: yes I did try that but same output

Comment: This is quite an easy one. Try the [`expect` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html) and see if it makes a difference. Meanwhile the above should work.

Comment: but that would require pexpect to be installed but client isn't ready for it

Comment: Have you considered using the [`stdin:` arg of `shell:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/shell_module.html#parameter-stdin) and just running `ssh-copy-id` directly under `shell:`?

Comment: sorry I didn't get your point, as far I understand if you directly fire only ssh-copy-id how can i give the password when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `\r` instead of `\n` and remove the double quotes. Below is working code.

```
     spawn ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.48.133
     expect "password: "
     send {{ remote_password }}\r
     interact
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the script was existing one command too early while executing the playbook with `-vvv` flag, which lead me to find `expect eof`.The `interact` may not be necessary in your case. I would insert this before `exit 0` and remove `interact`:

```
expect eof
```

So it would look like this:

---

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  vars:
  - remote_password: redhat
  tasks:
  - name: connecting to a remote host not an ansible slave
    shell: |
     set timeout 300
     spawn ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.48.133
     expect "password: "
     send "{{ remote_password }}\n"
     expect eof
     exit 0
    args:
     executable: /usr/bin/expect
```

Hopefully it works for you as it did for me.